# How can I find out Base ID of Fallout 4 creatures?

Tags: fallout-4, cheats

I need to spawn Institute and BoS common creatures, but I can't find their Base ID in all wikis. Is there any chance I could obtain ID of this creatures in game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the console, type `help xxxxx 0`, where xxxxx is the type of creature you're searching for (e.g. minuteman, raider, etc.) This will generate a list of items, quests and NPCs containing the search term.

The codes beginning with `00` are the ones to use. The codes beginning with `FF` will not spawn a functional creature and should not be used. You may need to scroll up to find the right code.